# How to filter below JSON based on the specific values in JSON expression or using Java?

Tags: java, json, expression

I want to filter the below JSON based on value of en-US key like Template1 or Template2

```
[
  {
    "en-US": "Template1"
  },
  {
    "en-US": "Template2"
  },
  {
    "en-US": "Template2"
  },
  {
    "en-US": "Template2"
  },
  {
    "en-US": "Template1"
  },
  {
    "en-US": "Template1"
  },
  {
    "en-US": "Template1"
  },
  {
    "en-US": "Template2"
  },
]
```

I have tried with below JSON expression but it didn't work.

```
$[?(@.en-US=='Template1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which library you're using. But the following expression works in https://json-everything.net/json-path

```
$[?(@['en-US']=='Template1')]
```

The issue seems to be that json path frameworks don't like properties with dashes in the name. Using the `['']` syntax was the only way I've found to circumvent that.